# Differentiate Ctrl+BackSpace from BackSpace in MobaXTerm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters, mobaxterm

I'm trying to configure zsh (.zshrc) in order to provide two different keystrokes, each one for a different action. While I need Backspace to just delete the previous character, control+backspace should be used to delete the whole previous word. Mu problem is that while I'm trying to capture the keystrokes codes via using ("Control+v" + keystroke), both seem to be the same '^H'

So, is there any other way in order to capture and differentiate both keystrokes in my system?

I made tests using both some virtual terminals like MobaXTerm, but I realized that it could be some tranlations inside the program, so I decided to make all the tests using the real console (directly via the vmware console).

Comment: In my `zsh`, the "regular" backspace is `^?`  - not sure of the relevance.

Comment: You need to configure your terminal to send a different escape sequence for Ctrl+Backspace. In the Linux console, it's possible (start with `man keymaps`, but I don't not really advise this: the Linux console has limited capabilities). With MobaXTerm, no idea. With any terminal emulator based on libvte, it's not possible. With good terminal emulators such as xterm, it's possible and documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices